# How to apply hover effect on IonButton so that it can open IonPopover as tooltip in Ionic-React?

Tags: ionic-framework, tooltip, popover, ionic5, ionic-react

```
<IonPopover
 showBackdrop={false}
 cssClass="theme-popover"
 event={popoverState.event}
 isOpen={popoverState.showPopover}
 onDidDismiss={() =>
 setShowPopover({
  showPopover: false,
  event: undefined,
 })
 }
>
   <IonContent class="ion-padding">
     Hello World!
   </IonContent>
</IonPopover>
```

How to apply hover effect on IonButton so that it can open IonPopover as tooltip in Ionic-React ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `triggerAction="hover"` to show popover on hover:

```
<IonButton id="hover-trigger">Hover Over Me</IonButton>

<IonPopover trigger="hover-trigger" triggerAction="hover">
   <IonContent class="ion-padding">Hello World!</IonContent>
</IonPopover>
```

See Documentation:
[ion-popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover)

Comment: I tried this method but I am getting a type error, i.e.
'trigger' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<PopoverOptions<ComponentRef>

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP is just not implementing correctly.